# How do I make IOrdering adapter available for ATFolder objects in a python script that reads a Zope Object Database?

Tags: position, plone, adapter

I am trying to query the portal_catalog like so:

```
plone = app['MY-PLONE-SITE-ROOT']

setHooks()
setSite(plone)

gsm = getGlobalSiteManager()

gsm.registerAdapter(ATFolder, (IOrderableFolder,), IOrdering, '')

results = portal_catalog(path={"query":"/MY-PLONE-SITE-ROOT"}, sort_on="getObjPositionInParent")

for brain in results:
    #do something with the folder tree structure
    print brain.getObject().getId()
```

If I omit the global site manager and registerAdapter line, then sorting on "getObjPositionInParent" raises a ComponentLookupError:

```
raise ComponentLookupError(object, interface, name)
zope.component.interfaces.ComponentLookupError: (<ATFolder at /MY-PLONE-SITE>, <InterfaceClass plone.folder.interfaces.IOrdering>, u'')
```

When I have those lines there as an attempt to register the adapter, I get:

```
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <Products.ATContentTypes.content.folder.ATFolder object at 0x47d7930>, <InterfaceClass Products.Archetypes.interfaces.schema.ISchema>)
```

which I do not really understand.  How should I correctly register the adapter for my script?  This is a script reading the ZODB from the filestorage file, so ZCML is not an option.

Thank you for your insight in advance.

Comment: If you use `bin/instance run YOURSCRIPT.py` it should work. I changed your script a little bit -> https://gist.github.com/maethu/3e86dce66ded5c3befc2

Comment: Thanks for that.  The script runs fine when I run it with bin/instance run instead.  The only problem is that I have to stop the running instance in order to do that.  Do you know if there is any way to register the Zope Component Architecture adapters in code?  The setSite( MY-PLONE-SITE ) method did not pull in any adapters.  I know this because after calling the setSite line, I getGlobalSiteManager to list all registered adapters, and none are printed.

Comment: If you are not using ZEO you should.  One should not but in the most trivial case run a Plone site / zope instance on a bare FileStorage without ZEO.  The bin/instance run thing should set up all the adapter registrations you need (you still should use setSite for local utility registration, though).

Comment: @user1075722 +1 on sdupton comment. use ZEO and 2 or more Zope clients. This way you can take down one instance to run your script and you don't have to care about de DB connection and the hole setup.